# Conflito de Versão no Build Gradle Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

Estou tentando utilizar o Firebase na minha aplicação, mas está dando erro de dependencia no gradle.

> Build.gradle (App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.juny.tinderx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Esse é o Erro que da:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta seu gradle completo!

Comment: Postei o gradle completo. Grato!

Comment: Provavelmente alguma biblioteca que vc está usando foi compilada com uma versão mais antiga das bibliotecas de suporte do google. Precisamos descobrir qual tem essa dependência. Pra isso vou te pedir mais um ajuda. Abra um terminal do grdle e digite: `./gradlew app:dependencies` depois poste na pergunte o resultado.

Comment: A árvore de dependencias ultrapassa o limite de caracteres, então enviei para um link:  https://pastebin.com/i4FSe58M

Comment: Quem está usando a support library velha é o firebase! Você está usando a versão mais nova? Vi que no seu gradle está a 11.8, que é a mais nova, mas nas dependências aparece 11.6!!! Tem certeza que está usando esse gradle? Que não tem nada perdido por aí usando versão mais antiga? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua árvore de dependência existem referências a versões mais antigas do firebase, que referenciam o play-services-basemente:11.6.0 que usam o support library mais antiga (25.2). Elas deveriam referenciar a versão 11.8.0 que, espera-se :-) utilize a versão 27.1.1 da support library:

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
```

Você precisa garantir que está usando a biblioteca mais nova do Firebase (e outras, se for o caso) para que todos usem internamente a versão mais recente da support library.

Há formas de forçar o uso da versão mais recente, tanto com script genérico, como manualmente (um exemplo onde isso é necessário é na integração com a biblioteca do Facebook que nunca está na versão mais nova da support library), contudo, como no seu caso seu projeto está começando, ainda sem muitas dependências, a melhor opção é sempre garantir que está usando todas as versões mais novas das bibliotecas envolvidas, ainda mais quando são do próprio Google.

Answer (score 0):

No dependencies do seu gradle coloque isto:

```
//Resolve conflitos da lib support
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion "27.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```